# Create a ethereum node with "current state" snapshot used for read only research?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to run an ethereum node which doesnt sync to anything and only stores the latest static state of the blockchain when it was first installed.

The reason for this is i want to be able to query balances but dont want the overhead of having to keep it synced. The balances dont need to be from the latest block.